# Undelete from SD card on Mac

Tags: macos, sd-card, file-recovery, picasa

I accidentally deleted some pictures off my SD card using Picasa on my Mac.  Is there any way to get them back?

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/107396/is-there-any-free-undelete-software-for-the-mac and http://superuser.com/questions/146560/mac-os-x-file-recovery-closed?

Comment: Actually it is not a duplicate.  I am asking about recovering files from an SD card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [PhotoRec](http://osx.iusethis.com/app/photorec).

Answer (score 0):

Um... If you don't have backup, you have to use recovery tool to recover sd card photos on Mac, and now, you hade better not use your sd card until photos are recovered. You can know more from this blog: [SD card photos recovery issues on Mac](http://www.mac-photos-recovery.com/sd-card-photo-recovery-on-mac.html). Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, please post all information relevant to your answer in your answer to avoid link rot